# How to enable jvm remote debugging in neo4j community edition windows and linux

Tags: neo4j, jvm

I would like to actually debug the extension running the Neo4j server from within Eclipse.

Can anybody give me a hint on how to do that.

I see lots of references to conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf , but cannot find the file neo4j-wrapper.conf  anywhere on my windows(the same thing for linux) server installation of Neo4j 3.5.11. I just have neo4j.conf.

can somebody tell me where I can put the following please in which file?

```
wrapper.java.additional=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -Xdebug-Xnoagent-Djava.compiler=NONE-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`neo4j-wrapper.conf` was merged into `neo4j.conf` in neo4j version 3.1.

See: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/manually-merging-neo4jwrapperconf-into-neo4jconf-in-neo4j-31/

So, in neo4j 3.1+, all config settings are in `neo4j.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Schwertfisch's answer, change suspend=n to suspend=y if you want to debug code that executes at startup, such as the constructor of a trigger. With suspend=y the VM waits until a debugger attaches before starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/server-debugging/
in file neo4j.conf
dbms.jvm.additional=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005